# Removing item from select list (Internet Explorer 10)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to remove selected options from select list.

```
$('#select_SettingsUser option:selected').each(function (i, selected) {
    var optn = selected.text;
    selected.remove();
});
```

The logic works on Firefox, Chrome. 
But on IE10, it says, `Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function each gives the `DOM` object you need to convert to `jQuery` object

Change

```
selected.remove();
```

To

```
$(selected).remove();
```

Or

```
$(this).remove();
```

> The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise
>   and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements
>   that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is
>   passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. **More importantly,
>   the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element**, so
>   the keyword this refers to the element, [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/each/).